# .forEach Giving Undefined Result

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a project where I want abbreviated state variables to become the full name of the state. I have been trying to do this using `forEach()`, but I keep getting undefined when I `console.log` it.

This is what I have:

```
console.log(orderLocationUS.forEach((state) => {
            if (state._id === 'NY'){
               state._id = 'New York'
              
        }}))
```

where orderLocationUS is equal to:

```
[
  { _id: 'NY', count: 1, totalSales: 20 },
  { _id: 'New Jersey', count: 1, totalSales: 30 },
  { _id: 'New York', count: 31, totalSales: 627 }
]
```

I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to fix this or what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: _"when I `console.log` it."_... what is **it**? There is no `console.log()` in your question code so how can we tell what you're trying to log

Comment: [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't return anything (aka `undefined`). Run your `forEach()` and _then_ log `orderLocationUS`

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles no, but the callback can modify the elements

Comment: This can be closed as a typo. Just log the result _after_ using `forEach` ~ https://jsfiddle.net/awzv6ugj/

Answer (score 0):

```js
orderLocationUS = [{
  _id: 'NY',
  count: 1,
  totalSales: 20
}, {
  _id: 'New Jersey',
  count: 1,
  totalSales: 30
}, {
  _id: 'New York',
  count: 31,
  totalSales: 627
}]

console.log(orderLocationUS.map((state) => {
  if (state._id === 'NY') {
    state._id = 'New York'
  }
  return state
}))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Javascript `map` returns a new array—does not modify the subject array.

Answer (score 0):

No. You are wrong.

`.forEeach` method returns `undefined`. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value

You should not modify the `orderLocationUS` state. You should use `map` to create a new array like:

```
orderLocationUS.map((location) => {
  if (!(location._id === 'NY')) {
     return location;
  }
  
  return {
    ...location,
    _id: 'New York',
  }
})
```

If you want to modify the object, you have to `forEach` first and put the `console.log(orderLocationUS)` in the next line because forEach returns `undefined` as said. But I never do this